# 24 game using Python3

Tags: python-3.x

24 is a mental arithmetic game, first played using poker cards. Given four integers, the objective is to produce the number 24 using the standard arithmetic operators +, −, ∗ and /, while consuming all four numbers in the process.
For example, given the numbers { 2, 3, 5, 6 }, one could do . . .
2 * 3 = 6 , 5 * 6 = 30 , 30 - 6 = 24 and so on

Note: The given numbers can be used in any order to produce 24.
Write a program that takes in four integers, and determines whether it is possible to reach 24 from those numbers. You can assume the number 0 will not form part of the input.

I am not sure how to let the function run my 4 inputs

```
import itertools
ints = input('Enter 4 integers: ').split()
n1=int(ints[0])
n2=int(ints[1])
n3=int(ints[2])
n4=int(ints[4])
def with_brackets(lst, ops_lst):
    for op in ops_lst: #calculate when no brackets
        expr1 = '('+lst[0]+op[0]+lst[1]+')'+op[1]+lst[2]+op[2]+lst[3]
        expr2 = '('+lst[0]+op[0]+lst[1]+op[1]+lst[2]+')'+op[2]+lst[3]
        expr3 = lst[0]+op[0]+'('+lst[1]+op[1]+lst[2]+')'+op[2]+lst[3]
        expr4 = '('+lst[0]+op[0]+lst[1]+')'+op[1]+'('+lst[2]+op[2]+lst[3]+')'

        for expr in [expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4]:
            try:
                t=eval(expr)
            except: #except zerodivision error
                pass
            if abs(t-24) < 0.001:
                return expr
    return 0
#return 4 numbers to calculate 24
def hasMethod(numbers, ops_lst):
    for lst in itertools.permutations(numbers):
        lst = list(map(lambda x:str(x), lst))
        #without brackets
        for op in ops_lst:
            expr = lst[0]+op[0]+lst[1]+op[1]+lst[2]+op[2]+lst[3]
            if abs(eval(expr)-24) < 0.001:
                return expr
        #with brackets
        expr = with_brackets(lst, ops_lst)
        if expr != 0:
            return expr
    return 0
#method of return 4 numbers to calculate 24，no way return"No Method"
def cal_24(numbers):
    ops = ['+','-','*','/']
    ops_lst = [[i,j,k] for i in ops for j in ops for k in ops]
    expr = hasMethod(numbers, ops_lst)
    if expr != 0:
    return expr
    else:
        return 'No method!'
#ways to calculate 24 at all situaions
def main():
    numbers_lst = [[i,j,k,l] for i in range(1,14) for j in range(1,14)\
                         for k in range(1,14) for l in range(1,14)]
    for numbers in numbers_lst:
        a = list(map(lambda x: str(x), numbers))
        methodInfo = "[%s,%s,%s,%s]: %s\n"%(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],cal_24(numbers))
        print(methodInfo)

main()
```

Expected results:

Example 1:

```
Enter 4 integers: 2 3 5 6

Yes! 24 is reachable from { 2, 3, 5, 6 }
```

Example 2:

```
Enter 4 integers: 1 1 1 1

Noooo :( 24 is unreachable from { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
```

Example 3:

```
Enter 4 integers: hello

Input must consist of 4 integers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very interesting.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import random, ast, re
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3: input = raw_input

def choose4():
    'four random digits >0 as characters'
    return [str(random.randint(1,9)) for i in range(4)]

def welcome(digits):
    print (__doc__)
    print ("Your four digits: " + ' '.join(digits))

def check(answer, digits):
    allowed = set('() +-*/\t'+''.join(digits))
    ok = all(ch in allowed for ch in answer) and \
         all(digits.count(dig) == answer.count(dig) for dig in set(digits)) \
         and not re.search('\d\d', answer)
    if ok:
        try:
            ast.parse(answer)
        except:
            ok = False
    return ok

def main():    
    digits = choose4()
    welcome(digits)
    trial = 0
    answer = ''
    chk = ans = False
    while not (chk and ans == 24):
        trial +=1
        answer = input("Expression %i: " % trial)
        chk = check(answer, digits)
        if answer.lower() == 'q':
            break
        if answer == '!':
            digits = choose4()
            print ("New digits:", ' '.join(digits))
            continue
        if not chk:
            print ("The input '%s' was wonky!" % answer)
        else:
            ans = eval(answer)
            print (" = ", ans)
            if ans == 24:
                print ("Thats right!")
    print ("Thank you and goodbye")   

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,but this one produce a different output

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that, someone else may provide better answer which gives a same output as you expected.